# @Html.DropDownListFor - How to set different color for a single item in list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, colors, html.dropdownlistfor

I wish to have one item in my DDL to be a different color (red). However the list comes from a table and is not hard coded in the page like

`<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>`

but rather as

`@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.Journal.Frequency, Model.JournalFrequencyList, "Select a Frequency", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Is there a way to make just one item a different color?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS?

Comment: One item ? Which item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your styles/css to make one item red color. Now you did not specify which specific item you want. With jQuery, you can select a specific option and set the color of that to red.

Assume your razor view renders a SELECT element like this

```
<SELECT id="fancySelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</SELECT>
```

And if you want to set the color of the option which has value attribute set to "2", you can use the below code

```
$(function(){

    $("#fancySelect option[value='2']").css('color','red');
    //you can also apply a css class if needed

});
```

If you want to update a different option, update your jQuery selector to get that.

**EDIT** : As per the comment

> is there any way to use the text as opposed to the value? Example
>   change if text is "Deleted"

You can update your jQuery selector to get the option with a specific text.

```
$("#fancySelect").find("option:contains('Deleted')").css('color','red');
```

I suggest you rely on option value than the text, you can set the value as a code which you can program against.

Comment: This work perfectly but is there any way to use the text  as opposed to the value? 

Example change if text is "Deleted":

<`option value="3">Deleted</option>`